# C programming: create instances of a struct inside a function

Tags: c, struct

I have a function `void createObject(int color, char value)`
Everytime I call this function, an object of

```
struct Object
{
  int color_;
  char val_;
};
```

has to be created inside this function. What is the best way to do this? Could someone please just give me an example? EDIT: Is it possible to have these objects collected in a list and/or an array?

Comment: There's only one way, so there is not much in terms of how many ways. Any C textbook, any [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm) would have it. It is syllabus, not a tricky problem

Comment: It rather important to provide the context when you are asking about "the best way". What we are going to compare? performance? design? semantic? You have to be very specific about the prerequisites.
Besides, I can't see why not just use common way any book will teach you for this cause I don't think there will be significant difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Object
{
    int color_;
    char val_;
} Object;

Object* createObject(int color, int value) {
    Object* o = malloc(sizeof(*o));
    o->color_ = color;
    o->val_ = value;
    return o;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Object* olist[10];
    olist[0] = createObject(1, 1);
    printf("%d:%d", olist[0]->color_, olist[0]->val_);
}
```

Comment: This still creates an `Object`. The OP is a little unclear in their question, I'm not sure if they're worried about the class declaration, or the object. It seems they are trying to create all objects once, then perhaps just reference them